# Why does ">" close my php query in wordpress when running a query for custom post types?

Tags: php, wordpress

When ever I paste a php query in my pages on wordpress under the text tab or in Divi builder's code module i find the code breaks into text.

I go to the preview or published view of the page and see the following:

'subjects', 'showposts' => 10 ) ); ?>

it appears to me that everytime I use ">", in my php code, it breaks and displays anything after it as text.

In efforts to test the displaying of custom field types and fields, Using CPT UI, i created the following custom post type:

Post Type Slug * subjects
Plural Label * subjects
Singular Label * subject

with a Advanced Custom Fields I created a field group:

Subject Descriptors: 
Date of Birth * date_of_birth Date Picker
Sex * sex Checkbox

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'subjects',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

I'm simply looking to display the name (post title) with the two custom fields of the custom post type on a page. I am not very knowledgeable on the topic and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In both the text tab and Divi's code module you can only enter html, not php.

The php you enter is handled as html.
If you would inspect the html source code on the frontend you will see it just will put the full code as html.

If you want to do php code you will have to change php files.

Side note `query_posts()` is very bad for [performance](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/10911).

Comment: how would I got about doing that?

Comment: I assume you are a new beginning coder, I suggest you first search tutorials and start learning. This sounds like it's to much for your current skill level.

Comment: what video recommendations would you give me for this problem? It is my only barrier for the project, once I can display the post types on the front-end I will be capable of completing it.